# Android/iOS app to encode a2dp stream other than SBC

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, codec

I've been looking for a solution to my problem but haven't been able to find any yet. Does anybody have knowledge of any mobile application for android or iOS that basically uses other codec than SBC for audio streaming over bluetooth? I actually need the device to stream AC3.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The codec support should be in the underlying bluetooth implementation of the device.
SBC is default and required for all bluetooth devices that support A2DP Audio streaming.
Additional codecs can be supported by the devices, for example the iPhone (iOS devices) support the AAC codec. 
Also note that for a particular codec to be chosen the same needs to be supported on the remote (headset) device also. 
So if you have an AAC capable headset then the iPhone will choose AAC over SBC for audio streaming.
Hope it helps